# How to generate a linked-list from a standard list in Python

Tags: python, linked-list

As part of a bigger project, I'm trying to generate a linked-list from a standard list. I've already looked through some topics regarding this problem on SO (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553576/converting-a-list-to-a-linked-list)) but most of codes have much different architecture than mine (linked-list is a class itself). Only the last answer was very similar to my solution.

What I try to accomplish here is to create a generator having, among others, a function creating linked-list from a given input (that's why the structure is rigid here). Also I can't touch *ListNode* class.

I've tried the following code but it returns only single element linked-list with the last element of the list as a node.

I have a feeling I am close but something is missing. I can create helper functions if that's required but ideally, I would like to avoid it. Has anyone any ideas? Where's the mistake?

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

class Creator:

    def populate(self, in_list):
        # creating the head node
        out_list = ListNode(in_list[0])
        curr = out_list

        # iterating over input list
        for i in in_list[1:]:
            curr = curr.next
            curr = ListNode(i)

        return curr


# Below the manual approach for a list of four elements/nodes
# manual_list = ListNode(1)
# manual_list.next = ListNode(2)
# manual_list.next.next = ListNode(3)
# manual_list.next.next.next = ListNode(4)

inputs = [1,2,3,4]
result = Creator().populate(inputs)

while result:
    print(result.val)
    result = result.next
```

Thank you!

Comment: "but most of codes have much different architecture than mine (linked-list is a class itself)." that's pretty standard, and I would argue the best practice. Why on earth are you even using a linked-list, though? Honestly, outside of a school exercise, I can never envision a good use-case for rolling your own linked-list implementation in python. you would almost always just use a regular `list` object, or perhaps a `collections.deque` As an aside, your `Creator` class should probably just be a regular function, it serves no purpose as a class...

Comment: Exactly - that's a part of an educational project dealing with non-standard data structures. I've never used these in my daily work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right direction, just take care of the pointer allocation after adding new node, also keep a reference to the first node and return that:

```
def populate(self, in_list):
    # creating the head node
    curr = ListNode(in_list[0])
    head = curr
    # iterating over input list
    for i in in_list[1:]:
      temp = ListNode(i)
      curr.next = temp
      curr = temp

    return head
```

Complete code:

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

class Creator:

    def populate(self, in_list):
        # creating the head node
        curr = ListNode(in_list[0])
        head = curr
        # iterating over input list
        for i in in_list[1:]:
          temp = ListNode(i)
          curr.next = temp
          curr = temp

        return head


# Below the manual approach for a list of four elements/nodes
# manual_list = ListNode(1)
# manual_list.next = ListNode(2)
# manual_list.next.next = ListNode(3)
# manual_list.next.next.next = ListNode(4)

inputs = [1,2,3,4]
result = Creator().populate(inputs)

while result:
    print(result.val)
    result = result.next
```

Comment: I am happy to help.